# AngularJS -> 2-decimal format and user limit choice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make number to have hundreths nad limit user choice for typing numbers between 0 and 1. For example, user is writing 0, so angular is converting to 0,00; if user is writing 1 then 1,00. How can i achieve this? I have the javascript function for limit, but i want to make it dynamic with angular.

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('CalcCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var num = 0.0;
    $scope.qty = new Quantity();
    $scope.num = num;
  });

function Quantity(numOfPcs) {
    var qty = numOfPcs;

    this.__defineGetter__("qty", function () {
        return qty;
    });

    this.__defineSetter__("qty", function (val) {        
        val = parseFloat(val);
        qty = val;
    });

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xnehel/ur26k9cx/6/

Comment: Actually do you just want to display to this format (you would need to create an angular filter) or to convert theses values ?

Comment: Display, found this http://jsfiddle.net/lancelarsen/Tx7Ty/ but got no idea where to implement it to my code `{{val | number:2}}`

Comment: Do you need to round the value ? Or do you need to force to two digit ?

Comment: Actually round would be prefered.

Comment: If @DanielCottone answer doesn't solve your problem, could you be a little more precise about the context and the use case ? There is many way to achieve that, but only one would meet your needs.

Comment: The idea is to convert normal number like 1 / 2 / 3... to 0.10 / 0.20 / 0.30.. up to 1.00; So as you wrote, filter might be the best option i think. So for example if someone types 200 it converts to 1.00. Someone types 34213 - it converts to 1.00. I want to make maximum at 100 (after auto-convertion it will be 1.00) and minimum at 0 (after auto-convertion it will be 0.00). Someone types -200 - it converts to 0.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with some field validation, [see this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tvHV2h0NndwfQaAoQEMe).

```
<form name="priceForm" novalidate>
  <label>Input currency</label>
  <input type="text" name="price" ng-model="price" ng-pattern="/^\d+[\.]\d{2}$/i" />
  <div ng-show="priceForm.price.$error.pattern">Invalid price</div>
</form>
```

If what you were actually wanting was to not allow the user to enter anything unless it matches this pattern, you need to write a custom directive or use some library which does this, [ui-mask](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask/master/demo/index.html) for example.

Comment: Hmm.. Gonna try to play with this mask, thanks for tips :)!